# On iOS, PDF position changes when turn to landscape

Tags: ios, pdf

On iOS, when a PDF  being viewed in portrait view, the location  changes when the device is rotated to landscape (it scrolls up). If you rotate again to portrait, it will go back to the previous portrait location.

**Exceptions**

1. Let us say we have 20 points in T&C screens. If I am on point 10 then when I change the orientation, I should be seeing point 10 somewhere in my display.
2. Otherwise, you should take me to first page when I change my orientation all the time (Not a good way but we can live with it).

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you are opening your pdf in a scrollview like setup:*

You need to save the scrolled position of your pdf file every time in method like `scrollViewDidScroll`. And when orientation gets changed, you will have to scroll back your scrollview to this position.